# CS50 PSet 2: Vigenere cipher Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, vigenere, cs50

I an new to the subject. I tried to debug this myself, but **Segmentation Fault Core dumped**, comes up and I cannot figure out why. Can someone help me please?

```
# include<cs50.h>
# include<stdio.h>
# include<ctype.h>
# include<string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])

{
    int i, n, no;
    string s;
    string vige = NULL;
    string msg;
    s= argv[1];
    for (i = 0; n = strlen(s), i < n ; i++)
    {  
        if (argc != 2 || (!isalpha(s[i]) ))
        {
            printf("Error \n");
            return 1;
        }

    }   

           printf("Secret message: ");
            msg = GetString();

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(s) ; i++)
    {
        if(isupper(s[i]))
        {
            vige[i] = s[i] - 65;
        }
        else if(islower(s[i]))            {
            vige[i] = s[i] - 97;  
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; no = strlen(msg), i < no; i++)
    {
        if(isalpha(msg[i]))
        {
            if(islower(msg[i]))
            {  
               printf("%c", (msg[i] + (vige[i] % n)) + 97) ;
            }
            else if(isupper(msg[i]))
            {
                printf("%c", (msg[i] + (vige[i] % n)) + 65) ;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", msg[i]);
            }
            return 0;
        }    
    }
}
```

In case there are other errors, I will figure them out myself, but the Segmentation fault is beyond my understanding.

Comment: And what does `gdb` say?

Comment: `s= argv[1];` what if I ran the binary like `./a.out`? then, `isalpha(s[i]`....

Comment: first change `for (i = 0; n = strlen(s), i < n ; i++)` to `for (i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n ; i++)`

Comment: @EugeneSh. or, just an option, move `n = strlen(s);` out of `for` loop statement altogether.

Comment: Actually it happens twice.

Comment: Then the only cause of segfault I can see is the `argv` thing. Or something with the hidden `string` api.

Comment: Oh no, wait. `vige` is NULL, but you are happily indexing it with `i`.

Comment: If I remove the NULL, I get an error saying: Variable vige is uninitialized. Initialize the variable 'vige' to silence this warning
    string vige;
               ^
                = NULL

Comment: You need to initialize it to a some preallocated space of sufficient size. As the implementation of `string` is hidden from us, I can't tell how.

Comment: The code has a problem that needs to be addressed before going further into debug operations.  there are two valid and one optional ways to declare the main function:  1) int main( int argc, char *argv[] )  2) int main( void )  and optionally 3) int main().  Note: 'char *argv[]' and 'char **argv' are the same thing.

Comment: Always compile with all warnings enabled.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic')  Then, after fixing the main() declaration, a long-long sequence of problems will be listed by the compiler.  suggest, for portability, replacing all 'string' type declarations with 'char *' type declarations and replacing the 'GetString()' function with 'readline()'.

Comment: given the posted code, if the input string is 30 characters or longer, then a large portion of the characters being output by the printf() statements will be unprintable and can seriously mess with the operation of the terminal you use when running the program.

Comment: along with the several compile time problems, if the code is run, with out fixing those problems, then assignments are being made to the char pointer 'vige'.  However, vige contains NULL (pointer to address 0) so any accessing off that pointer will result in undefined behaviour, leading to a seg fault event.  Suggest calling malloc() to allocate memory for the copied/modified input string

Answer (score 1):

`vige` is initialized to `NULL`, but later on it is dereferenced using the index notation `vige[i]`, which is an attempt to access the memory the code doesn't own, causing memory violation and thus undefined behavior.